# Does Stylus Have a Feature Similar to the Less @import (reference) Feature?

Tags: stylus

In Less, it is possible to only import those parts of a stylesheet that are referenced - as explained here:  http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference

Is there a similar function in Stylus?  If so, how can this be done?

Comment: Looks like for stylus if you want to import a block like that, you should move that block to it's own file, then import in the two files. If you need to import a lot of such blocks, you'd need to use globing. Although, you can probably achive similar results by making what you want to import a [mixin](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/mixins.html).

Comment: Perhaps we have to rewrite everything in the imported file into a "placeholder" to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for stylus if you want to import a block like that, you should move that block to it's own file, then import in the two files. You could also make use of "index style" of import.

Overall though, it doesn't look like it has that specific functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Stylus implements this via either [mixins](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/mixins.html) or [placeholder selectors](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/extend.html#extending-placeholder-selectors).  Placeholder selectors are probably closer to what you expect.

For example, if your reference file has a `.clickable-button` selector, you'll have to rewrite it to a placeholder: `$clickable-button`.

```
// shared.styl
$clickable-button
    cursor: pointer
    &:hover
      color: light-blue

// main.styl
@require './shared'
.go-button
  @extend $clickable-button
```